# .net core 6.0 Cannot use aes decryption on android since no types of padding are supported

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, aes, padding, maui

I have been coding an android messaging app for a recent project and decided to write it in .net MAUI. Upon trying to decrypt messages using a provided aes key, cipher and initialisation vector I encountered a problem with the padding. After testing my encryption/decryption mechanism on a windows machine I later discovered that the padding would not work on android for the AES decryption, hence the error.

The problem is though that upon hovering over the AES.Padding options, none of them are compatiable for android according to visual studio?

How can I go about implementing this? Thanks

The AES encypt/decrypt functions are just the standard ones listed in documentation of netcore https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-6.0

Comment: If you write "initialisation vector" that this means you are using CBC? If yes are you really sure you want to do so on a new app? CBC is an outdated mode, today a cipher mode like GCM which also includes authentication/integrity checking is recommended.

Comment: Hiya, I produce my key and IV by using the Aes service I have instantiated, I'm not too familiar with the difference between CBC and GCM. The exact code I've used for the encryption and decryption is in the microsoft documentation I linked, however the key is produced for the chat session between two users when the class is instantiated. using

`  myAesService.GenerateKey();
            myAesService.GenerateIV();`

Comment: Everyone uses BouncyCastle for encryption in dotnet and java. I'm sure it has what you need.

Comment: @carlin.scott Thanks I'l look into bouncycastle! Hopefully it runs on android

Comment: Which padding are you actually talking about? Maybe PKCS#7, which is called PKCS#5 in the Java world (for historical reasons)? It should be intuitively clear that this piece of information is needed to answer the question. Java and .NET support the most common paddings (and algorithms), so BouncyCastle is often not needed at all. Please don't be so vague in your description and/or post the relevant C# and Android code.

Comment: @Topaco The padding I was using was PKCS#7 I managed to solve it and it turned out since I was debugging between a windows client and android client the padding is different for the platforms i think? I made sure that the padding everywhere on both clients was set to PKCS#7 and it solved it! First time posting on stackoverflow, next time I'll try be more specific

Comment: Glad you have solved it. Consider adding "Your Answer" below, describing what you changed. This may help others in the future! (Basically the above comment, ideally with two small snippets of code, one that did not work, the second that does work.)